# .png file not saving correctly matplotlib

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, png

While saving a multiple grid figure in png with 300 as dpi, I lose quality

However this error does not occur while saving the figure as a pdf.

Here is the small portion of the code that saves the image generated:

```
fig.savefig(filepath, format = 'pdf'
             ,bbox_inches='tight',dpi=300)

fig.savefig(filepath, format = 'png'
             ,bbox_inches='tight',dpi=300)
```

Is there a way to obtain a good resolution png of an image such as the above without having to resort to using pdf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.pdf` images are vector graphics, and thus preserve all information. In other words setting `dpi=300` in the pdf creation doesn't do anything (unless you have set specific objects to be rasterized using `rasterized = True`).

`.png` images are raster graphics (e.g. [check this out](http://vector-conversions.com/vectorizing/raster_vs_vector.html)).  Therefore you have to adjust the `dpi` to get the balance of filesize vs. quality that you want. In other words, the image *is* saving correctly, it's just lower quality than the 'perfect' pdf.

The choice of image output format depends on how you will use it. Vector graphics (`.pdf`, `.svg`) are great if you have simple plots that you want to scale (zoom) perfectly. However, if you are plotting many points (>10,000 or so), this can lead to very large filesizes. In this case it may be better to *rasterize* the figure because a person can't see that many data points anyway.

"Which *raster* format should you use?" `.png` and `.jpg` are the most common. The former has better compression for images with large patches of the same color, while the latter has better compression for high pixel variability (e.g. photographs).  [Check this out for more info.](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/jpeg-vs-png-image-quality-or-bandwidth/5385/)

Note that while `.png` is considered 'lossless', it is only so in the sense that it preserves the rasterized information. Information is still lost when saving/converting to rasterized format.